# NSCoder: how to encode/decode [Data] array

Tags: swift, appkit

I'm having troubles encoding/decoding an array of Data (basically file bookmarks) in NSCoder protocol.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
class ClosedFiles: NSCoder {
    static var supportsSecureCoding = true
    let bookmarks: [Data]
    init?(with coder: NSCoder) {
        if let bm = coder.decodeObject() as? [Data] {
            bookmarks = bm
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    init(bookmarks: [Data]) {
        self.bookmarks = bookmarks
    }
    
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeRootObject(bookmarks)
    }
}
```

I encode this object in my app delegate:

```
func application(_ app: NSApplication, willEncodeRestorableState coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encodeRootObject(ClosedFiles(bookmarks: closedFiles))
}
```

This throws the error in runtime:

> Ignoring exception: This decoder will only decode classes that adopt
> NSSecureCoding. Class '_TtCC7MyApp11AppDelegate11ClosedFiles' does
> not adopt it.

I'm following the [apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssecurecoding) to conform to NSSecure, but it doesn't seem to work.
I tried a few other method, but nothing seems working: coder.encode(), coder.encodeConditionalObject, and whatever else I found.

Any thought what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well it should conform to `NSSecureCoding`, not inherit from `NSCoder`. Please show how "nothing seems working" when conforming to `NSSecureCoding`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it but it shows these error: `Nested class 'AppDelegate.ClosedFiles' has an unstable name when archiving via 'NSCoding'`. I looked it up, but can't figure out what's wrong (there's a SO answer that I should know precise encoded class name, but don't do any runtime type casting in encoding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a lot of changes for your class to support `NSCoding` (actually `NSSecureCoding`.

- Your class must extend `NSObject`
- Your class needs to conform to `NSSecureCoding`
- You need the correct signature for the `init(coder:)` initializer
- The `supportsSecureCoding` property needs to be static
- The implementation of the two `NSCoding` methods need to be written correctly to support secure coding.

Here's your class with all of the changes.

```swift
class ClosedFiles: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    let bookmarks: [Data]

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        if let bm = coder.decodeArrayOfObjects(ofClass: NSData.self, forKey: "bookmarks") as? [Data] {
            bookmarks = bm
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    init(bookmarks: [Data]) {
        self.bookmarks = bookmarks
    }

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(bookmarks as [NSData], forKey: "bookmarks")
    }

    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I tested these changes in a Playground using the following code:

```swift
do {
    let closed = ClosedFiles(bookmarks: [ "Hello".data(using: .utf8)!, "There".data(using: .utf8)! ])
    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: closed, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    let dupe = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [ClosedFiles.self, NSArray.self, NSData.self], from: data) as! ClosedFiles
    let str1 = String(data: dupe.bookmarks[0], encoding: .utf8)!
    print(str1)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This gives back the expected results.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes, I had multiple problems after wrestle with this code for a while. I think the most important part I missed early was that I had to cast `Data` to `NSData` before encoding.